# Installing single-pole thermostat for electric baseboard heat, possible short?

Tags: electrical, thermostat, electric-heat

I am replacing an old 2-pole dial thermostat for 2 baseboard heaters with a new digital model (Honeywell RLV4305A). I was surprised that though it says it is rated for 220, it is only single pole and thus breaks only one leg. According to [the instructions](https://www.honeywellstore.com/store/images/pdf/honeywell-rlv4305a1000e-5-2-day-programmable-electric-heat-thermsota-installation-guide.pdf), I should just connect the two white wires together. There is 110V between the line and load wires (expected) so when these are connected the circuit is raised 110V, which I don't love, but ok.

So having done that, to double-check things, I put my meter probe on the baseboard heater chassis itself and measured to the ground in a nearby receptacle. **Got 110V**!

So I am asking for confirmation in my thinking that a) this heater case has always been energized when it was on and we are lucky no one was hurt b) the heater(s) need to be replaced or re-wired by a pro

Comment: that does not sound good, which one did you use 2 or 4 wire

Comment: 4 wire method. I just took apart the heater connection boxes and found the grounds were not connected

Comment: So connect the grounds, check for correct wiring and take new readings. We can't really confirm anything based on someone else's readings.

Comment: pure luck, none was killed

Comment: I connected the grounds as they should be, breaker doesn't trip, and all seems to be good. But... is there now a chance current is leaking?